# Index was outside the bounds of the array string

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting an error for following code: Here my pagedata.length is 495 and i am using 57 of these in variable k.

```
for(int k = 0; k < pagedata.Length;k++)
        {
            string[] textdata = pagedata.Split(new char[0]);
            string stringforemail = textdata[k];
            if (stringforemail.Contains("@") && stringforemail.Contains("."))
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                //tr.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                tc.Text = stringforemail;
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
```

of cause there is something wrong in my code, but i cant figure out the mistake.. please help me understanding error.

Thank you

Comment: what length is text data[]?

Comment: Apparently your cycle is running until `pagedata.Length` but it is higher than `pagedata.Split(new char[0]).Length` - textdata[k] is outside the bounds.

Comment: we have no way to really help you.
Pagedata.Length > Split.NewChar.Length, so your inconsistent in what your looking for. A regex might help.

Comment: `pagedata.length` is number of characters in `pagedata`, but your loop variable `k` is being used as an index for `texdata` which is the result of splitting `pagedata`. these two are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @Maharshi, what do you want the **textdata[]** to contain? (is it going to be single characters/words/lines/etc)?

Comment: jbutler483 --- A word

Comment: triple_r    -----  hmmmm you are correct, but what should be the modification????

Comment: Calvin Smith ------ yes yes, i understood now, but what is the correct way to solve this one????

Comment: VDohnal ----- yes you are right. i'll modify my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to split your text on a new, empty character array. That gives you an array with one item, the value of `pagedata`.

Hence, your `textdata[k]` will fail since that uses the length of `pagedata`, which is more than 1 (the length of the array).

I don't know what you are trying to do with it, but your code should look something like this:

```
string[] textdata = pagedata.Split("your split string");

foreach (string stringforemail in textdata)
{
    if (stringforemail.Contains("@") && stringforemail.Contains("."))
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        //tr.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        tc.Text = stringforemail;
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

Where you replace `your split string` with the text you use as delimeter.

Comment: it looks like hes splitting pagedata on '0'.
Therefore textdata[k], k should be 0, the first elemenet of the array should always be there.

Comment: Actually, textdata[k], as long as he has passed in more than 0 characters in his pagedata, will always have a result in the 0 location

Comment: the bit that's getting me is *using 57 of these in variable k.*

Comment: eh, regardless, patricks answer is a good answer. Its always easier to use a foreach loop than doing the math behind a for loop.

Comment: @jbutler483: That is okay. The `foreach` loop will do the work for you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I see that now - i've just never been introduced to it before. I'll have to read up and get used to using it a bit more :P

Comment: @Maharshi: Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

try adding (at the end of the for loop):

```
if(k==textdata.Length)
{
break;
}
```

that way once this has been completed, the loop will break.